# android: Why attribute clipChildren doesn't work in RelativeLayout but works in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm very confused about why attribute clipChildren doesn't work in RelativeLayout but works in LinearLayout. 
I put a LinearLayout and a RelativeLayout in a parent RelativeLayout. And set clipChildren to 'false' of these three layouts. But it shows difference.
codes as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

        <Button
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

        <Button
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and result as follows:
[image of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNNPA.png)